# Market-basket: calculating support/confidence/lift/rules

Tags: python, market-basket-analysis

How can I calculate support/confidence/lift on a dataset in order to find frequent itemsets and determine association rules, in python? What would be the most effective method for predicting and offering recommendations on a test set of incomplete "shopping carts"? I am limited to the Anaconda distribution so I cant use packages such as orange3, etc.

Comment: Have you tried using apriori algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

I've done this (using anaconda) with the following libraries.

```
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules
```

Have a look [here](https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/frequent_patterns/association_rules/).

Answer (score 0):

Python package [Orange3-Associate](https://orange3-associate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripting.html), which contains functions for mining association rules and seems to be what you are referring to, should be able to be installed on Anaconda's Python distribution with Python's internal `pip` command, i.e.

```
pip install orange3-associate
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my post- I can only use the packages that are in the native distribution already. No pip install.

Comment: You could get Orange3-Associate into [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/), or is this, being a separate conda channel, also forbidden?

Comment: Forbidden :( Otherwise the project would be much simpler